# make git command with params

Tags: git, console

if there is a way in console of kubuntu 18 to set command with current datetime 
and current directory, like :

```
git commit -m "CurrentDir project update on CurrentDatetime "
```

?
Thanks!

Comment: you should write shell script for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with sub-commands, like

```
git commit -m "$(pwd) project update on $(date)"
```

`$(...)` executes the contents beforehand and uses the result here
`pwd` outputs current dir
`date` outputs current date/time

Comment: Cool!. But it puts all path. Can it be only project directory name? And digital format of date, not national ?

Comment: Check date formats [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/date.1.html). About the output of `pwd`, I guess it's quite trivial string manipulation. I'm not that confident in bash itself though. I would have searched something along the lines of `cut 's/^(.*)\/([^\/]*$)/\2/'`